# specific word count in document based on other field value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want word count example "Hello" where parentId is 1 in below object using elastic search(6.4)

```
{
    "id" : "7",
    "parentId":"1",
    "transcription" : "hello hello hello hello hello hello hi  search 5555"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [_termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html).

Using termvectors, you can get statistics at field level.

**URL** : indexname/_doc/docid/_termvectors?fields=transcription

**Output**:

```
{
  "terms": {
    "5555": {
      "term_freq": 1,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "position": 8,
          "start_offset": 48,
          "end_offset": 52
        }
      ]
    },
    "hello": {
    "term_freq": 6,             <----- This is your word count.
      "tokens": [
        {
          "position": 0,
          "start_offset": 1,
          "end_offset": 6
        },
        {
          "position": 1,
          "start_offset": 7,
          "end_offset": 12
        },
        {
          "position": 2,
          "start_offset": 13,
          "end_offset": 18
        },
        {
          "position": 3,
          "start_offset": 19,
          "end_offset": 24
        },
        {
          "position": 4,
          "start_offset": 25,
          "end_offset": 30
        },
        {
          "position": 5,
          "start_offset": 31,
          "end_offset": 36
        }
      ]
    },
    "hi": {
      "term_freq": 1,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "position": 6,
          "start_offset": 37,
          "end_offset": 39
        }
      ]
    },
    "search": {
      "term_freq": 1,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "position": 7,
          "start_offset": 41,
          "end_offset": 47
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you shailesh for solution , but i want query similar to  where clause because document id is different my search criteria(parentId is another attribute in document) is different. can u suggest some other solution

Comment: No. You need to know the document id before you use termvectors.

Comment: can i apply another condition along with word count in termvector?other than termvector can i have some other solution